# Cocoa app, how to show the badge label when app isn't running?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, notifications

I've noticed the Spark mail app manages to show a badge count even when the app isn't running. The app is a mac app store app so it must not be using any private APIs. Is there a way to do this? Currently I'm only able to do the following while the app is running:

```
[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] dockTile] setBadgeLabel:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", 10]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a Dock tile plugin. See the documentation for `NSDockTilePlugIn` for information on how to do this:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocktileplugin

EDIT: Okay, if you want to do what Spark is doing, here it is:

Spark is using Apple Push Notifications to inform you of new e-mails that come in. For e-mail accounts other than Gmail or Outlook, this generally means they store your username and password on their server, which seems "OMG!" levels of creepy to me, but YMMV. When their server notices that you have a new e-mail, they forward the notification to you.

A description of what Spark is doing can be found here: https://blog.readdle.com/how-we-handle-your-account-information-in-spark-1b42f4acef73

If you want to implement push notifications yourself, [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/517/) shows generally how to do it, and [this sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PushyMac/Introduction/Intro.html) may be helpful as well.

Comment: DockTile plugins are not allowed on the App Store

Comment: I've recently had an app rejected by the App Store review team for using it. I realise the documentation is quiet on this though.

Comment: Okay, from looking at Spark, near as I can tell, it appears that it is using push notifications to be notified when a new e-mail comes in, using `-[NSApplication registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:]`. It looks like if you pass `NSRemoteNotificationTypeBadge` to that, you can have it update the application badge when a notification comes in.

Comment: Some possibly relevant links: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/517/ , https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PushyMac/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Edited the answer with information on Spark and push notifications.